# C# timer isn't working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, timer

This is Form1

I am trying to use the variable level from form2 to set the timer's interval in form1

```
    int time = 0;


    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time++;
```

The timer's interval is set depending on the value of the variable "level" which is located in form2

```
       if (Form8.level.Equals("expert"))
        {

            timer1.Interval = 10000;


            if (time == 10000)
            {

                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("time ended");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            timer1.Equals(60000);


            if (time==60000)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("time ended");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is Form2

This is the variable that i want to use in form1

```
     public Static String level = ""; 


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();


        Form1 f1 = new Form1(); 
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Is the Load event properly attached? Where are you creating the instance of Timer?

Comment: Use the debugger. What is the interval when you start the timer the first time? You only access the other form once it ticked.

Comment: @ChrisK i don't have to create an instance, i just simply drag the timer from the toolbox and start coding, that's what I've been taught.

Comment: Ok. In that case set a breakpoint in the Form1.Load method and in the Form1.timer1_Tick method to check, that both events are properly raised.

Comment: Also see if there is a closing `}` after `timer1.Start();`. The code you posted here seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @nvoigt the interval is set to 10000

Comment: You tried if (time > x) instead of equals ?

Comment: @ChrisK yea i only forgot to add the closing } when i posted the question.

Comment: @Max yes i tried but it didn't work either

Comment: I think the problem is not really the code itself. I think the algorithm is just not doing what you intend to do. I've written a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General advice

Ok, I don't think that your code is really wrong, there are just some issues that might create the impression that your code isn't working.

First of all, I'd suggest that you consider naming your classes more appropriately. I personally tend to name my Forms after their functionality. So you might consider to rename `Form8` to `DifficultyForm`. This way it's much easier to understand your code. Also, a name like `elapsedLevelTime` gives an idea of the purpose of the timer. If someone else looks at your code, the person won't really know the *use* of `timer1`.

## Recap of the problem

Now let's quickly recap what the code should do: The user seems to select a difficulty of some sort. Then, another window is shown. In the shown window, a timer should increment, until a certain time is reached. Then the text "time ended" will be displayed.

As you described, you created a lot of stuff in the Designer. So I assume that all Events are attached properly. This leads to the conclusion, that the culprit is located in your `timer1_elapsed`, the code that actually *counts* the elapsed time:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time++;
    if (Form8.level.Equals("expert"))
    {

        timer1.Interval = 10000;


        if (time == 10000)
        {

            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("time ended");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        timer1.Equals(60000);


        if (time==60000)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("time ended");
        }
    }
}
```

## What the algorithm does and possible pitfalls

When debugging algorithms, [Rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is - despite the funny name - a valuable approach. So let's step through your code.

- The timer is started when your form is loaded. You didn't really specify the timer settings, however a default timer has the Interval of 100ms. So the `tick` method is raised around 10 times every second.
- When the timer ticks, `time` will be increased by one. So after 1 Second, `time` will be 10.
- Now you are checking if the chosen level is expert. So we have to options here:

  a. The level is expert. In that case you set the interval to `10000`. This will cause the `tick` event to be raised every 10 seconds. You then check if the `time`-variable is `10000`. If that's the case, you end the timer and display "time ended". Here are two issues:

  1. You are using `if (time == 10000)` instead of `if (time >= 10000)`. This way, if the `time` variable is updated without the check, your timer will never *finish*
  2. Due to setting the interval to `10000` the condition will be reached after `10000 * 10s` seconds, which is around 27 hours.

  b. The level is not expert. Here we have some issues with your code as well:

  1. The `timer1.Equals(60000);` is a useless statement here. The `Equals` method will basically check if `timer1 == 60000;`.
  2. Same possible issue with the `if`-condition. See above: a1
  3. Due to the default interval of 100ms, the condition will be reached after `60000 * 0.1s`, around 100 min.

## Possible solution

Here are some suggestions to improve the code:

- Set the timer interval outside the tick event. It looks like it needs
  to be set only once.
- Check the usage of `timer1.Equals(60000)`
- Check if you really wanted these long intervals
- Make sure you understand what value `time` contains, and how often it is increased

I tried to recreate your problem in a small WindowsForm project with a possible solution:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer secondMeasureTimer;
    private int elapsedTime; //in seconds

    private string level = "expert";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        secondMeasureTimer = new Timer();
        secondMeasureTimer.Tick += secondMeasureTimer_Tick;
        secondMeasureTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second resolution
    }

    void secondMeasureTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "secondMeasure", "secondMeaserTimer ticked at " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine); // Output every time the event is raised for debugging purposes
#endif

        elapsedTime++; // increas time every second

        if (level == "expert" && elapsedTime >= 10)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "10 seconds elapsed";
            secondMeasureTimer.Stop();
        }
        else if (elapsedTime >= 60)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "60 seconds elapse";
            secondMeasureTimer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void timerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (secondMeasureTimer.Enabled)
        {
            secondMeasureTimer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            elapsedTime = 0;
            secondMeasureTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is not a web application you can use static variables

i.e,
 public staic String level = "";

Then accessing `formname.level` will give you the value of that.

Just try this may help you.

Comment: yes it's not a web application, it helped thanks. But still the timer didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing try the following method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Form1 f1 = new Form1(this); 
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Calling `close()` on a form disposes all controls on it, so it will also dispose the timer. Calling `Hide()` will remove the form from view, but it will remain 'loaded'. A much better solution would be to put the timer in its own context, not on a form.

Comment: @jesse: It wont visible for the user and it will close when application is closed

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.